# Why is the type of bind for random takes an extra StdGen?

Tags: haskell, monads

Continuing on in the [tutorial](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html), in section *A more complex side effect: Random Numbers* I come to this:

```
bind :: (a → StdGen → (b,StdGen)) → (StdGen → (a,StdGen)) → (StdGen → (b,StdGen))
```

when the type of the "randomised function" (as the author calls it) is as follows:

```
a → StdGen -> (b,StdGen)
```

Furthermore, the bind is defined as:

```
bind f x seed = let (x',seed') = x seed in f x' seed'
```

*Question*: Why does the bind have an extra `StdGen` the end of it's signature? Shouldn't it be:

```
bind :: (a → StdGen → (b,StdGen)) → (StdGen → (a,StdGen)) → (b,StdGen)
```

My reasoning goes as follows:

1. Bind takes a function `f:: a -> StdGen -> (b,StdGen)` and the "output" `StdGen -> (a,StdGen)`.
2. It applies the `f` to the `a` and `StdGen`, and returns whatever the signature of `f` says it would - which is just `(b, StdGen)`:

   ```
   f::a -> StdGen -> (b,StdGen)
   ```
3. Even following bind implementation, `f` is applied to both a value `x'` and a `seed'` of type `StdGen`, so it's result MUST be a tuple!

   ```
    bind f x seed = let (x',seed') = x seed in f x' seed'
   ```

Anywhere I went wrong there? Any help appreciated!

N.B.: For future readers, the author's definition of `bind` is equivalent to standard one except with the arguments flipped: `flip . >>=`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take your type:

```
bind :: (a → StdGen → (b,StdGen)) → (StdGen → (a,StdGen)) → (b,StdGen)
```

Now, I'm 100% with you on your first point:

> Bind takes a function `f :: a -> StdGen -> (b,StdGen)` and the "output" `StdGen -> (a,StdGen)`.

But your second worries me:

> It applies the `f` to the `a` and `StdGen`.

Where did you get a value of type `a` from? Where did you get a value of type `StdGen` from?

The answer to both of these questions is "you don't have one lying about"; however, since you *do* have a `StdGen -> (a,StdGen)` lying about, you could get both if only you had one more `StdGen` parameter. And that's where the extra parameter comes from.

Now, a slightly higher-level explanation. Part of the problem (I think) is that these type signatures are a bit too cluttered to read comfortably. We need some abstractions. What we're trying to model here are probability distributions, which we're modeling as their sampling functions. So, we can say a distribution over `a` is a function that knows how to sample from the distribution and return an `a`:

```
type Dist a = StdGen -> (a, StdGen)
```

Now, not all distributions are so flat as all that. For example, the Bernoulli distribution is "sort of" a `Dist Bool`, but it's also parameterized on the probability of choosing `False`. We can write its type thus:

```
bernoulli :: Double -> Dist Bool
```

So, we can model parameterized distributions as functions that return distributions; equivalently, we can think of functions that return distributions as parameterized distributions.

Now with this high-level interpretation in mind, the type of `bind` becomes much more readable:

```
bind :: (a -> Dist b) -> (Dist a -> Dist b)
```

This says that `bind` is the function that tells how to first sample from an `a` distribution, then use that `a` as a parameter when sampling from the `b` distribution. Not only that, but with this type alias, it almost becomes unthinkable to write a type for `bind` that doesn't have the "extra" argument.